# Recursive algorithm that returns every pair of a set

Tags: algorithm, recursion, set

I was wondering if any algorithm of that kind does exist, I don't have the slightest idea on how to program it...

For exemple if you give it [1;5;7]
it should returns [(1,5);(1,7);(5,1);(5,7);(7,1);(7,5)]

I don't want to use any for loop.

Do you have any clue on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two cases: list is empty -> return empty list; list is not empty -> take first element `x`, for each element `y` yield `(x, y)` and make a recursive call on the tail of the list. Haskell:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs [] = []
pairs (x:xs) = [(x, x') | x' <- xs] ++ pairs xs

--*Main> pairs [1..10]
--[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(2,9),(2,10),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(3,7),(3,8),(3,9),(3,10),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8),(4,9),(4,10),(5,6),(5,7),(5,8),(5,9),(5,10),(6,7),(6,8),(6,9),(6,10),(7,8),(7,9),(7,10),(8,9),(8,10),(9,10)]
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know is the algorithm used is a recursive one or not, but what are you asking for is the `itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2)` method from Python and I suppose the same thing is implemented in other programming language, so you can probably use the native method.

But if you need to write your own, then you can take a look at [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) (on this site) for some ideas